# How to press space when i press escape

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, onkeypress

In following exemple, how can I do the "space bar pressed" action when i press enter button ?
What I want is when I press enter, it will add a space, like when I press the space bar.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.onkeypress = function(){return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)||(event.charCode == 32);};
```

```css
textarea{
  height : 100px;
  width : 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Here you can only press numbers and space bar !"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
if(event.charCode == 13){
        textarea.value = textarea.value + " ";
}
```

Complete code:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.onkeypress = function (event) {
    if(event.charCode == 13){
        textarea.value = textarea.value + " ";
    }
    return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode == 32);
};
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zj0dx68v/1/)

Comment: @Antoine It works for me, I can enter only numbers and space and `enter` adds space as requested. Isn't it working for you? P.S I am using Chrome

Comment: @Antoine It was working on Chrome and not Firefox since Firefox was not recognizing `event` variable by default and had to be explicitly defined. I updated the code, it should now work :)

Comment: Argh, i'm on IE 10 xD

Comment: @Antoine Goodluck with that thing bro xD

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.onkeypress = function(event){
  var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if(!(code == 13 || code == 32 || code == 8 || code == 46 || (code>= 48 && code <= 57))){
    event.preventDefault();
   
  }
 
};
```

```css
textarea{
  height : 100px;
  width : 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Here you can only press numbers and space bar !"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thx, bu there i can press a lettre, i just wan't number, space and enter.

Comment: U want only enter alphabet and nothing else?

Comment: only numbers, spaces and enter

Comment: My enter key need to return me a space, like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31807445/4787098